# ember data 3.28 rollback after save

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Is there any way to rollback model after a series of model.save or model.destroyRecord, and partial failed

```
try {
  await testModel1.save(); //success
  await testModel2.save(); //fail
} catch (error) {
  // How to rollback both testModel1 and testModel2 here?
}
```